# Jmeter Jtl files are not getting created

Tags: jmeter-maven-plugin

I have created a maven project. Jmeter scripts are running fine but Jtl files are not getting created.

If we run the scripts from maven from Command line I am getting HTML report but when running the same from Jenkins I am not getting data in the HTML report.

Can someone help on this please

Answer (score -1):

When running from jenkins the results will be created by default in jenkins build folder. Did you check the folder with the right build number?

Comment: Yeah after changing some configurations in pom.xml jtl files are getting generated

Comment: What changes? what did you miss?